# Почему письмо не адаптируется в мобильной яндекс почте?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, email, media-queries

Есть адаптивное html письмо, в gmail работает отлично а вот в почтовике яндекса как будто вся его адаптивность игнорируется. В чем может быть дело, или яндекс вообще не дружит с media queries

Comment: Не только Яндекс, почти все почтовые клиенты не дружат с медиа запросами

Comment: Почтовые агенты вообще имеют кучу ограничений, недоступность медиаквери - меньшая из проблем.

Comment: Если большинство почтовых клиентов не поддерживают медиа запросы, тогда как адаптивить письма другими способами?

Comment: никак .... тут нет никаких полифилов и прочего. Надо просто смириться и использовать то, что дают. По сути это все напоминает разработку под IE6, только в ещё более суровых условиях.

Comment: Что ж благодарю за довольно развернутые ответы. Буду использовать то что есть. Напоследок подскажите пожалуйста работают ли медиа запросы в почтовике на iPhone под IOS? Нет возможности протестить это.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/437434/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-iphone